# Do Canadian visa biometrics have an age cut off?

Tags: visas, canada

Are biometrics required for a person who is 71 years old? Two people have applied for a Canadian visa, but only the younger one got a request for the biometrics.

Comment: Canadian requirements for biometrics vary according to nationality, travel itinerary, and the visa you're applying for. There are also some age exceptions (although those I found were for 79yrs+). If you can post the details I've mentioned we might be able to offer more help. You might also find [this page](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/biometrics.asp) useful.

Comment: OP hasn't returned to clarify details. Putting on hold.